# GWT Internal error while validating appengine-web.xml

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, font-awesome

When I try to deploy to GAE I get the error:

*XML error validating appengine-web.xml against appengine-web.xsd*

My *appengine-web.xml* looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>whatever</application>
<version>0-8-4</version>

<!-- Configure serving/caching of GWT files -->
<static-files>
  <include path="**" />

  <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
  <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />

  <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
  <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />

  <!-- To use Font Awesome in Firefox -->
  <include path="/../**" >
       <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </include>
</static-files>

<!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
<system-properties>
   <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>

<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

The lines that are causing the error are:

```
  <!-- To use Font Awesome in Firefox -->
  <include path="/../**" >
       <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </include>
```

Before they were like this but that also gives the same error:

```
<include path="/../font" >
    <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
</include>
<include path="/../css" >
    <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
</include>
```

Can anyone see what's the problem?

**edit** This is what my war file structure looks like:
[image]

Comment: What does your `war` directory structure look like? Also, having a path go up beyond your root directory (using the `/../**` pattern) seems strange to me. If you put the `font` and `css` directories directly under the `war` directory and use `path="/font"` and `path="/css"` patterns in your `include` statement, you might be set.

Comment: OK, I thought the path was relative to `WEB-INF`, where `appengine-web.xml` is located. Anyway, I tried with two `include`s with `path="/font"` and `path="/css"` and I got the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it worked for me like this:

```
<!-- Configure serving/caching of GWT files -->
<static-files>
  <!-- To use Font Awesome in Firefox -->
  <include path="**" >
     <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </include>

  <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
  <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />

  <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
  <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />

</static-files>
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)